# having difficulty in extracting out id in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can see item and item id as it loops to render on the screen but i don't see the value of id when i click on any of the Tile where Tile is a div and react styled component.

```
class CategoryOffers extends React.Component {
  passidtopointscreen =(id)=>{
    console.log("id is", id);
    localStorage.setItem('points_id',id);

    this.props.history.push('/marketplacepoints')
     debugger
   }
  render() {
    debugger
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        {this.props &&
          this.props.cards_data &&
          this.props.cards_data.map(item => {
            return (
              <Tile onClick={(item)=>this.passidtopointscreen(item.id)}>
                <ImageWrapper>
                  <Image src={item.logo} height={'24px'} width={'73px'} />
                </ImageWrapper>
                <CardString>{item.offer_summary}</CardString>
              </Tile>
            )
          })}
      </Wrapper>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

---

```
    onClick={()=>this.passidtopointscreen(item.id)}
```

---

while adding `item` there you create new instance for this keyword for no reason

Comment: To add to this: the argument passed from onClick into your event-handler is a SyntheticEvent. Because of the scope you overwrite the item value from props with the SyntheticEvent

Answer (score 1):

By having the same argument-name as your already decleared argument (item), you overwrite the outer argument. There should be no reason for you here to use the event-argument, if I have understood your question correctly.

I would also suggest avoiding localstorage and instead make use of the state.

I made the component into functional one here:

```
    import React from "react";        
    const CategoryOffers = ({history,cards_data}) => {
      const passidtopointscreen =(id)=>{
        localStorage.setItem('points_id',id);
        history.push('/marketplacepoints')
       }
         return (
          <Wrapper>
            {
              cards_data?.map(item => {
                return (
                  <Tile onClick={(event)=>passidtopointscreen(item.id)}>
                    <ImageWrapper>
                      <Image src={item.logo} height={'24px'} width={'73px'} />
                    </ImageWrapper>
                    <CardString>{item.offer_summary}</CardString>
                  </Tile>
                )
              })}
          </Wrapper>
        )
      }
    }
```